# How to throw with a "gorilla grip"

Tags: technique, dodgeball

I am familiar with the so called Gorilla grip in dodgeball, but find it hard to throw hard and accurately from there, as opposed to a palm grip. What is the correct technique I should be using?

Comment: I am not sure if I can get an answer if I ask *I am familiar with the so called knuckle ball grip in baseball, but find it hard to throw hard and accurately as opposed to a fast ball grip. What is the correct technique I should be using?*

Comment: @Rathony I am not 100% sure if you mean I'm more likely to get an answer that way...? I get that there is a good degree of parallelism between the two, but with a few relevant differences, so not fully sure how to read that :)

Comment: Well, you need shoulder power and grip to throw whatever ball hard and accurately. Every pitcher in the world knows how to throw a knuckle ball, but less than 1% actually throws it because they don't have the strong enough grip and shoulder power to throw it and it could injure their arm more easily. Even if your question could be answered definitively here, how would you understand it and practice it? I don't think it could be well explained in this kind of forum even if there is an expert on gorilla grip.  I think you should ask your coach.

Comment: I get that, although the presence of competitive dodgeball (and therefore of highly qualified coaches) where I live is virtually non-existent, which leads me to asking here. It's a fair point, but at least here I have some chance of finding a competent user who can either give me a "Gorilla 101" explanation, or point me to online resources I haven't been able to spot, as the best I have so far is a short video with a couple demostrations only!

Comment: Good luck to you.